# Android app crashing as soon as I run it on device

Tags: android

I have an android application that runs well on an emulator I created in Android Studio but it does not run when I try it on a device. The device was initially incompatible with the application due to minSDKversion incompatibility so I ran it on the emulator. After making changes in the `build.gradle` of the app (downgrading minsdkversion from 18 to 17 so that it runs on my rooted device) I was able to successfully install it on the device but as soon as it runs it crashes saying "Unfortunately MyApplication has stopped running".  On running it on another device with a higher API level (Moto G Android 5.1) I do not get this problem, but the Micromax Canvas A110Q gives this problem.

Here is the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.amrit.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' // will not include LICENSE file
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar')
}
```

The minsdkversion was initially 18. Nothing else has been changed. 
What could be the problem? Any suggestions?

Here is the logcat:

```
03-24 10:36:42.148 17838-17838/com.example.amrit.myapplication
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.amrit.myapplication.NotificationAnalyze

        at com.example.amrit.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)

        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)

        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)

        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)

        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)

        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)

        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView txtView;
    private NotificationReceiver nReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        nReceiver = new NotificationReceiver();
        Intent s = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationAnalyze.class);
        startService(s);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("com.example.amrit.myapplication.NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_EXAMPLE");
        registerReceiver(nReceiver, filter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(nReceiver);
    }



    public void buttonClicked(View v){

        if(v.getId() == R.id.btnCreateNotify){
            NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationCompat.Builder ncomp = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            ncomp.setContentTitle("My Notification");
            ncomp.setContentText("Notification here");
            ncomp.setTicker("Notification here");
            ncomp.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            ncomp.setAutoCancel(true);
            nManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), ncomp.build());
        }
        else if(v.getId() == R.id.btnClearNotify){
            Intent i = new Intent("com.example.amrit.myapplication.NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE_EXAMPLE");
            i.putExtra("command","clearall");
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            sendBroadcast(i);
            Log.d("clearing", i.toString());
        }
        else if(v.getId() == R.id.btnListNotify){
            Intent i = new Intent("com.example.amrit.myapplication.NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE_EXAMPLE");
            i.putExtra("command","list");
            sendBroadcast(i);
        }


    }

    class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String temp = intent.getStringExtra("notification_event") + "\n" + txtView.getText();
            txtView.setText(temp);
        }
    }



}
```

NotificationAnalyze:

```
public class NotificationAnalyze extends NotificationListenerService {

    /**
     * A constructor is required, and must call the super IntentService(String)
     * constructor with a name for the worker thread.
     */

    public static String TAG = "NotificationListenerTesting";
    private NLServiceReceiver nlservicereciver;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        nlservicereciver = new NLServiceReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("com.example.amrit.myapplication.NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE_EXAMPLE");
        registerReceiver(nlservicereciver, filter);
        Log.d("create", "herer");
    }
    @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(nlservicereciver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        TAG = "onNotificationPosted";
        Log.d(TAG, "id = " + sbn.getId() + "Package Name" + sbn.getPackageName() +
                "Post time = " + sbn.getPostTime() + "Tag = " + sbn.getTag());
    }
    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        TAG = "onNotificationRemoved";
        Log.d(TAG, "id = " + sbn.getId() + "Package Name" + sbn.getPackageName() +
                "Post time = " + sbn.getPostTime() + "Tag = " + sbn.getTag());

    }
    class NLServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getStringExtra("command").equals("clearall")){
                Log.d(TAG, "here");
                NotificationAnalyze.this.cancelAllNotifications();
            }
            else if(intent.getStringExtra("command").equals("list")){
                Log.d(TAG, "here2");
                Intent i1 = new  Intent("com.example.amrit.myapplication.NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_EXAMPLE");
                i1.putExtra("notification_event","=====================");
                sendBroadcast(i1);
                int i=1;
                for (StatusBarNotification sbn : NotificationAnalyze.this.getActiveNotifications())
                {
                    Intent i2 = new  Intent("com.example.amrit.myapplication.NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_EXAMPLE");
                    String packageName = sbn.getPackageName();
                    String text = "", apkPath="";
                    text = "Notification Text : " + sbn.getNotification().tickerText + "\n\n";
                    text = text + "Package name of notification :  " + packageName + "\n\n";
                    try
                    {
                        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm path " + packageName);
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                        apkPath = bufferedReader.readLine().substring(8);
                        Log.d("APK path : ", apkPath);
                        text = text + "Check for 'install' in Notification Text, If so \n\n";
                        text = text + "APK Path : " + apkPath + "\n\n";
                        text = text + "Sending apk for upload \n";


                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    }


                    i2.putExtra("notification_event", text);
                    sendBroadcast(i2);
                    i++;

                    new UploadData().execute(apkPath);

                }
                Intent i3 = new  Intent("com.example.amrit.myapplication.NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_EXAMPLE");
                i3.putExtra("notification_event","===== Notification List ====");
                sendBroadcast(i3);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u post the logcat?

Comment: edited with logcat now

Comment: Can u post your MainActivity?

Comment: Seems like you're using a new API call somewhere in your code. That's why it works on new OS devices and not on old ones.

Comment: Can you show your MainActivity.java around line 29?

Comment: Also, what does NotificationAnalyze import?

Comment: import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.os.IBinder
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification
import android.util.Log
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent
import android.widget.Toast
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.util.List

Comment: Added MainActivity code

Comment: `com.example.amrit.myapplication.NotificationAnalyze` where is it??

Comment: you should show `NotificationAnalyze` code

Comment: edited with NotificationAnalyze

Comment: Is this because NotificationListenerService (in NotificationAnalyze) requires minimum API 18 and is giving an error because I changed minSDKversion to 17 and 16 that the error is coming?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio/ gradle? If you are, you need to include your `NotificationAnalyze` activity inside your `Manifest.xml` file. If you did not do that, Android Studio cannot recognize your activity class. One of the main reason this error (`NoClassDefFound`) occurs is because your activity is not inside the `Manifest.xml` file

Comment: It has been declared as a service in the Manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

`NotificationListenerService` which you use [is available starting from API level 18](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) and is not supported for lower versions of API.

For old api (<18) you may use [AccessibilityService](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html). [Here's a manual](https://pankajchunchun.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/capture-toast-or-notification-using-accessibility-service/) how you can do it.

Comment: If I set minsdkversion to 18 as it was initially then the NotificationListenerService problem would be solved, yes, but it won't run on my device as its API is 17. How do I get both things done?
I thought rooting could help me get around min API problem but it didn't

Comment: how can I get this app to block the installation of other apps on the device? This app will get notification access, so I thought blocking the installation through its notification could help. Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: you can't block installation of other apps on Android. there's no API for that